# MVVMCross add image as attachment using Email Plugin

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MVVMCross Email Plugin. Is there any way to attach an image to email message?

```
Mvx.Resolve<IMvxComposeEmailTask>().ComposeEmail(to, String.Empty, subject, body, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IMvxComposeEmailTaskEx](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/blob/master/Email/MvvmCross.Plugins.Email/IMvxComposeEmailTaskEx.cs) instead of [IMvxComposeEmailTask](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/blob/master/Email/MvvmCross.Plugins.Email/IMvxComposeEmailTask.cs).
It provides method with `attachments` param:

```
void ComposeEmail(
    IEnumerable<string> to, 
    IEnumerable<string> cc = null, 
    string subject = null, 
    string body = null, 
    bool isHtml = false, 
    IEnumerable<EmailAttachment> attachments = null, 
    string dialogTitle = null
);
```

---

**UPD:**

> What ContentType I must set?

Chose your content type from this list of [mime-types](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/).
E.g. `image/jpeg` for jpeg images or `image/png` for png.

Comment: I want to add image as attachment, so what ContentType I must set?
UPDATE: ok, i've set ContentType as "image" and it works perfectly. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

although its too late i have found a beautiful and easy way of doing this with Xamarin.Essentials plugin , Below is the sample code

```
private async void OnFeedBackClick()
    {
        EmailMessage aEmail = new EmailMessage
        {
            Subject = Paths.AppName + "feedback",
            To = new List<string>() { Paths.AppEmail },
        };

        foreach (string item in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Paths.AppDataDirectory,"*.log",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        {
            aEmail.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(item));
        }

        await Email.ComposeAsync(aEmail);
    }
```